# Node-rdp-js enable clipboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, rdp, mstsc

Hello :) I am using  this project to open rdp connection in browser
[mstsc.js](https://github.com/citronneur/mstsc.js). This repository using [node-rdp-js](https://github.com/citronneur/node-rdpjs)  for operation between JS and microsoft rdp service.  How to enable clipboard config on this node-rdp-js, any solutions will be nice.

I tried to modify rdp.js and sec.js to add clipboard support but i failed.

Comment: I don't see that node-rd-js depends on `node-rdp`? https://github.com/citronneur/node-rdpjs/blob/master/package.json

Comment: ye i noticed it ealier :D

Comment: Since it is not implemented already, it would need coding effort to create the channel. [This](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-RDPECLIP/[MS-RDPECLIP]-171201.pdf) and [this](http://claudihome.com/html/LR/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_RDP_working_with_clipboard_data.htm) may help in your quest

Comment: I will read it but would be nice if someone have some example with js or typescript implementation.

Comment: anyone implemented this function?

Comment: as i remember nope